# Oracle Stored Proc BLOB IN Parameter ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, blob

What is wrong with this stored procedure in Oracle? I am getting errpr "ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error" while executing.

Please stored proc, execute statement and error below.

```
************************ORACLE STORED PROCEDURE *****************
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE lobWriteAppend_proc(in_blob IN BLOB, File_Name IN VARCHAR2) IS
Lob_loc    BLOB;
Buffer     RAW(32767);
Amount     Binary_integer := 32767;
BEGIN
select FILE_CONTENT INTO Lob_loc from VM_FILE_TBL where SOURCE_FILE_NAME = File_Name FOR UPDATE;
/* Fill the buffer with data... */
/* Opening the LOB is optional: */   
DBMS_LOB.OPEN (Lob_loc, DBMS_LOB.LOB_READWRITE);   
/* Append the data from the buffer to the end of the LOB: */
DBMS_LOB.WRITEAPPEND(Lob_loc, Amount, Buffer);   
/* Closing the LOB is mandatory if you have opened it: */
DBMS_LOB.CLOSE(Lob_loc);   
COMMIT;   
EXCEPTION
 WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
   NULL;
 WHEN OTHERS THEN
   -- Consider logging the error and then re-raise
   RAISE;
END lobWriteAppend_proc;
/
***************** EXECUTE COMMAND ************************
EXEC LOBWRITEAPPEND_PROC(utl_raw.cast_to_raw('SampleString'), 'AG_FG_Dev_Refresh_2016234512323.xml');
************** ERROR ************
ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error
ORA-06512: at "VM.LOBWRITEAPPEND_PROC", line 45
ORA-06512: at line 1
********************
```

Thanks,
Sanjay

Comment: Your `buffer` variable that you attempt to append to the blob column is empty while you specify an amount of 32767 in `Amount` to copy. This causes the exception. Do you actually want to append the (unused) parameter `in_blob` instead? Youmay use `dbms_lob.append(lob_loc,in_blob);` in this case.

Comment: Thank you so much, I missed to initialize buffer. Instead of using buffer I used the function provided by you. It is working fine now. Thank you again for quick answer.